# Converting NSString to NSDate

Tags: ios, iphone

I have to convert Jan 24, 2014, 7:27:56 PM to NSDate 
but facing problem to convert it due to Upper case PM/AM , i am using this code , but it giving me nil.

```
NSString *stringDate = @"Jan 24, 2014, 7:27:56 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
NSLog(@"Date 1 : %@",date); //2013-02-28 12:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: What approaches have you tried to either change your input to the correct format, or change your date formatter to accept the input in its current form?

Comment: You also need to set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`. If you don't, your code won't work on devices using a language other than English.

Answer (score 3):

Your formatter string contains sequence "yyyy hh", however the stringDate has "yyyy, hh". Try this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm:ss a"];
```